# git not using global config file or public key

Tags: ssh, git, key-authentication, ssh-agent, github

I've setup a global git username and password while logged in as `root` on my Fedora server with the following commands:

```
git config --global user.email "[my email]"
git config --global user.name "[my username]"
```

I have also created and saved a public key to my `~/.ssh` directory, and added this to the ssh agent with the following command:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/[filename]
```

After checking the ssh-agent was running using

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

I then added the key from `~/.ssh/[filename].pub` to the *SSH and GPG keys* section on github.

I have checked in `~/.gitconfig` and the username and email are clearly listed there.

However, whenever I try to do anything on github it's still prompting me for a username and a password every time. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably connecting to `https` URL of your GitHub repositories. Your url in the `.git/config` looks somehow like this:

```
url = https://github.com/User/repository.git
```

If you want to use `ssh` authentication, you need to use `ssh` protocol and therefore url like this:

```
url = git@github.com:User/repository.git
```

Comment: The weird thing is, it's still prompting me for username and password even when I'm just trying to clone another repo. Do I need to put my own username before the url of the repo I'm cloning...?

Comment: How does the url you are using look like?

Comment: `git clone http://github.com/robertdavidgraham/massscan`

Comment: That is `https` url. Clone with `ssh` as explained above: 
`git clone git@github.com:robertdavidgraham/massscan` and it should do the job for you.

Comment: `root/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: identifyfile
/root/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: it is `identityfile`

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon. It's now at least asking if I want to connect using RSA, but it's still failing with `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` even after I've cloned to my own repo.

Comment: `ssh -vvvT git@github.com` should give you more information why does it fail.

Comment: I'll see what I can work out from here. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ok, that sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that it has to use the key for github.com

In your `~/.ssh/config`, add

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<private key>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. Could this be anything to do with the fact I didn't have a ~/.ssh/config file untiI I created one to add the lines you suggested?

Comment: No, *when* you create the file does not matter. It just has to exist once you try to establish an SSH connection (see also [Jakuje's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305427/184914) to check if you really connect via SSH).